# Multi-line word made with symbols

Tags: r

Does anybody know if there is a package to make an specific word made by symbols? Something like the image above.

`"HOLA"` word made with `#`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `Rfiglet` package which does something similar :

```
Rfiglet::figlet('HOLA', font = 'starwars')

 __    __    ______    __          ___      
|  |  |  |  /  __  \  |  |        /   \     
|  |__|  | |  |  |  | |  |       /  ^  \    
|   __   | |  |  |  | |  |      /  /_\  \   
|  |  |  | |  `--'  | |  `----./  _____  \  
|__|  |__|  \______/  |_______/__/     \__\
```